# Racket: evaluating a tree with arithmetic operators

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, binary-tree, racket

I want to evaluate a tree with arithmetic operators as symbols. So a tree is:

```
(define-struct op-tree (op left right))
```

`left` and `right` could either be a number or an 'operator as well. What I have so far:

```
(define (eval-op-tree tree)
  (local (
      (define (get-root-op i)
        (cond
          ((symbol=? i '+) +)
          ((symbol=? i '-) -)
          ((symbol=? i '/) /)
          ((symbol=? i '*) *)))
      (define (get-info i)
        (cond
          ((number? i) i)
          ((symbol=? '+ (op-tree-op i)) (+ (get-info (op-tree-left tree)) (get-info (op-tree-right tree))))
          ((symbol=? '- (op-tree-op i)) (- (get-info (op-tree-left tree)) (get-info (op-tree-right tree))))
          ((symbol=? '* (op-tree-op i)) (* (get-info (op-tree-left tree)) (get-info (op-tree-right tree))))
          ((symbol=? '/ (op-tree-op i)) (/ (get-info (op-tree-left tree)) (get-info (op-tree-right tree)))))))
(cond
  ((not (symbol? (op-tree-op tree))) "root has to be an op")
  (else
   ((get-root-op (op-tree-op tree)) (get-info (op-tree-left tree)) (get-info (op-tree-right tree)))))))
```

This seems to work for `(make-op-tree 'any-operator any-number any-number` but doesn't work for a tree whose length is greater than 1 and the program runs for ever... What do I do wrong?

Comment: Look for the place where you're recursing into the parts of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be seriously simplified; for example, if your `op` field could be expressed as a procedure instead of a symbol, you could just say:

```
(define (eval-op-tree tree)
  (if (op-tree? tree)
      ((op-tree-op tree) (eval-op-tree (op-tree-left  tree))
                         (eval-op-tree (op-tree-right tree)))
      tree))
```

and then

```
> (eval-op-tree (make-op-tree + 1 2))
3
> (eval-op-tree (make-op-tree + 4 (make-op-tree * 7 8)))
60
```

If you need to use symbols, you can use an association list:

```
(define (eval-op-tree tree)
  (if (op-tree? tree)
      ((cadr (assq (op-tree-op tree)
                   (list (list '+ +) (list '- -) (list '* *) (list '/ /))))
       (eval-op-tree (op-tree-left  tree))
       (eval-op-tree (op-tree-right tree)))
      tree))
```

then

```
> (eval-op-tree (make-op-tree '+ 1 2))
3
> (eval-op-tree (make-op-tree '+ 4 (make-op-tree '* 7 8)))
60
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I see the problem. You have a couple of minor issues.

- You've got two completely independent evaluators; one is nested *inside* the other. There's no need to have two separate ones.
- Move your `get-info` function outside of that local; it has no dependency on the surrounding function. Or... it *shouldn't*, anyway. (That's your bug.) After you find your bug, you still have some cleanup to do.